# Memory error during merge dataframes in Dask

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a following structure of dask dataframe, where unique values of VAR is 31:

```
          DATETIME    START       END        VAR     N     A     W
2016-08-15 06:00:00 21600000    22499000    var1    0.0   0.0   0.00
2016-08-15 06:00:00 21600000    22499000    var2    220.0 3.0   211.40
2016-08-15 06:00:00 21600000    22499000    var3    100.0 20.0  218.42
```

and total shape is (814463, 8)

I was trying to "unpivot" VAR values to separate columns with next code:

```
# df is Dask dataframe
var_df = None
dt_df = None
for var in VAR_CONSTANTS:
    tmp_df = df3[df3.VAR == var]
    tmp_df = tmp_df.rename(
        columns={
            'N': var[:-1] + '_N',
            'A': var[:-1] + '_T',
            'W': var[:-1] + '_W'}
    )
    tmp_df = tmp_df.drop(['VAR'], axis=1)
    if not var_df:
        var_df = tmp_df.copy()
    else:
        var_df = dd.merge(var_df, tmp_df, how='inner', on=['DATETIME'])
```

Got Memory Error after merging 10 vars.

Server has 50 GB RAM, and 6 cores. Dask is the latest version

I am hating this code, and maybe there is main problem in code not in Dask.

Comment: When you say "where unique values of VAR is 31," do you mean that `VAR` is a categorical column where each cell in that column is one of 31 possible values?

Comment: Also, you note that `df` is a Dask DataFrame - do you mean that `df3` is, as well? I don't believe you should be subsetting a mutating large components of a DataFrame in Dask, and then attempt to merge it into another `var_df`. What it looks like you are trying to do and you current workflow seems better if just performed in Pandas. Your dataframe shape appears to be 8 wide and then (I think you shape output is backwards?) I suppose 800k tall. That should be small enough to just hold in memory and have Pandas operate on it without Dask.

Comment: 1. VAR is a categorical column with 31 possible values
2 *df3 is Dask dataframe*, created from pandas before.If rewrite to Pandas there is also everything hangs up (Memory Error)